# preg_match_all for a string

Tags: php, string, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm look to just get `America/Chicago` from this string

```
Local Time Zone (America/Chicago (CDT) offset -18000 (Daylight))
```

and have it work for other TimeZones, like `America/Los_Angeles`,`America/New_York` and so on. Im not very good with `prey_match_all` and also, if someone can direct me to a good tutorial on how to properly learn that,because this is the 3rd time ive needed to use it.

Comment: I'm sure many people including myself have learned here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your solution with my regular expression

**Code**

```
    $in = "Local Time Zone (America/Chicago (CDT) offset -18000 (Daylight))";
    preg_match_all('/\(([A-Za-z0-9_\W]+?)\\s/', $in, $out);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($out[1][0]);

 ?>
```

**And OUTPUT**

```
America/Chicago
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: it is working for me,if my answer is useful to you please don't forget to vote up and accept it.i would be glad.

Comment: if your ever in houston after next june, i'll buy you a beer. thanks! works like a charm

Comment: @Fabian Buentello, Thanks a lot.

Comment: It doesn't work for timezone like `America/Los_Angeles` because of the underscore that isn't match in your character class.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the regex: `\((\S+)`

```
preg_match_all('/\((\S+)/', $in, $out);
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:\((\S+))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```